# Допустимо ли такое уточнение?

Tags: пунктуация, уточнения

Примером являются выполненные «Центратомтехэнерго», с привлечением сторонних организаций отрасли, работы по реализации вышеуказанных мероприятий на Ростовской, Калининской, Балаковской и Нововоронежской АЭС.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустимо. Предложение громоздкое, и обособление обстоятельства с пояснительным значением помогает правильно прочитать предложение. Рядом стоящие существительные ***организаций отрасли работы*** требуют интонационного разграничения.

***Примером являются выполненные «Центратомтехэнерго», с привлечением сторонних организаций отрасли, работы по реализации вышеуказанных мероприятий на Ростовской, Калининской, Балаковской и Нововоронежской АЭС.***

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными в формах косвенных падежей с предлогами, обособляются для попутного пояснения или смыслового выделения. Такое обособление факультативно. В Вашем примере, на мой взгляд, необходимо.

Answer (score 0):

Позвольте, если это уместно, задать следующий вопрос: насколько необходимо данное уточнение? «Центратомтехэнерго» является исполнителем работ (неважно, какими способами: своими силами или с привлечением других организаций), а "сторонние организации", если я правильно понимаю, - субподрядные. Насколько важно их упоминать, если нет поимённого перечисления? Если это уточнение опустить, тогда Вы сделаете "удобоваримым" предложение, насыщенное названиями.